# How to safely check if the chrome driver is compatible with the chrome browser in python selenium on Windows?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

If the chrome browser is updated,
there will be some errors while running the old script.

Is there a safe way to check if the driver is still compatible?

Answer (score 1):

All the browsers: Google Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera etc are being developing and updating continuously. This causes the Selenium WebDrivers for each of those browsers to be updated accordingly to support the latest versions of the browsers.
However there are tools like [`webdrivermanager`](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)  that will automatically download the updated `webdriver` versions